# Rank of symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, symbolic

I can't figure out why Mathematica can't calculate rank of a symbolic matrix. Please take a look at the attached screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

If you need the full source code then you can find it in the "z_x_expression.nb" file via the [link](https://github.com/v-tsepelev/Topological_recursion_for_symmetric_chromatic_polynomial).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because of `MatrixForm`. Remove it from the definition of `A`. Also, please provide copy-pastable code instead of screenshots to help users help you.

Comment: @anderstood, many thanks!